# Spike in trading volume in Sensex - 1st Feb 2019

Tags: india, trading-volume, bse-india

I won't pretent to be an economic genius because I'm not. I'm trying to plot some data in a graphical format for a friend of mine and while working on the project I noticed something strange. From 17th of December 2018 to 6th of February 2019, there were massive spikes in the trading volume of Sensex, the likes of which were and to this date have never been seen. At its peak (on 1st of Feb, 2019), the trading volume is registered 31.8 Million.[image]

From what I understand according to my limited knowledge of economics (and a few hits on Google :P), the volume represents <s>the number of transactions during a trade</s> the number of shares traded. (Thanks Bob, for correcting me in the comment)

I googled the incident and surprisingly nothing turned up. I was wondering if someone can explain what happened back then. Or maybe it's only a glitch in the data. The data is downloaded from [Yahoo Finance](https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EBSESN/history?p=%5EBSESN).

[image]

Comment: Volume represents the number of shares traded not the number of trades.

Comment: @BobBaerker: Thanks for correcting me. :) Do you know why did Sensex see such high volume back in those days?

Comment: Sorry but I don't.  I am not familiar with the Sensex market.